# How to replace specific string from column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `varchar` column in my table which has some data like:

```
"#306 loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc"
"#302 loream ipsum aaabbbceefec"
"#330 loream ipsum aaabbbccsds"
```

I want to replace `#3XX` like regex syntax in C# or JavaScript.

How to implement this in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you show sample output?

Comment: just replace string with blank like 'loream ipsum aaabbbcc' code# REPLACE(StringValue,'#3XX','')

Comment: Is it always the first 4 characters?

Comment: Then this is a simple SUBSTRING.

Comment: @SeanLange: but length is not fixed od data

Comment: You never told us what you actually want to replace with.

Comment: Which is it? You said it is always the first 4 and then it isn't. Is it always the the first xxx characters before the first space? There needs to be some kind of a pattern for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188043.aspx) function to achieve this.

```
Declare @String Varchar(100) = '#306 loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc'

SELECT STUFF(@String , 1,5,'')

Result: loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc
```

You can make use of the [`RIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177532.aspx) function to achieve this.

```
Declare @String Varchar(100) = '#306 loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc'

SELECT RIGHT(@String , LEN(@String) - 5)

RESULT:  loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring if it is always first 4 characters..

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set 
@str='#306 loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc'

select substring(@str,5,len(@str))
```

Answer (score 1):

To Remove it , use this query.Since the length of the string which you want to remove is always 4.

```
     UPDATE table-name SET column-name = RIGHT(column-name, LEN(column-name) - 4)
```

But run only one time because it is UPDATE query

For MySql you have to use the length() function like that,

```
     UPDATE table-name SET column-name = RIGHT(column-name, LENGTH(column-name) - 4)
```

Comment: The point from the OP is they don't know what string it is. It is a pattern, not a fixed string.

Comment: Not sure if the `Replace` function will be a good choice since the string to be replaced is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

if it is possible to split string by space then follow below one

```
Declare @str Varchar(100) = '#306 loream ipsum aaabbbqqqcc'
set @str =substring( @str ,CHARINDEX(' ', @str) , len(@str) - CHARINDEX(' ', @str)+1)
```

In this one you don't need any default length or default replacement text.